# Index Third last occurrence of the integer, 1 in array

Tags: php

Below my code. I want to find the index/position of third last occurrence of the integer 1

```
$arr = array(2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1,10,11,12,1);
$result = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $result[$val][] = $key;
}

echo end($result[1]);// 11 but it should be 6
```

Comment: You don't want the `end` of `$result[1]`, you want the *third last* index, i.e. `count($result[1]) - 3`…

Comment: sorry@ deceze not working.have you understood what i want

Comment: How exactly did you apply my above hint?

Comment: i want the index of third last integer 1  not count

Comment: ‍♂️ To get the *third last index* in your `$result[1]` array, you need to subtract 3 from the total length of the array. That then is the index in `$result[1]` which contains your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr = array(2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1,10,11,12,1);
$result = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $result[$val][] = $key;
}
//count total record of $result[1] and third last index
$count = count($result[1]);
$thirdLastIndex = $count-3;
echo isset($result[1][$thirdLastIndex]) ? $result[1][$thirdLastIndex] : 'No record';
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/QWVOY)